# Search after Id which is contains extra characters

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Have page where Employees can Search after Id and Id is look like this `00320` and type of Id is integer and Id in database look like this 320 , i just add two 00 in my view where i showing id and also add two 00 in my Action where im saying Id Contains Search Parameter i also debugged and i can see Id Contains 00320, but when i Search after 00320 it cant find any match.what did i wrong! did i miss something! 
Can anyone please help me or point me in to right direction!
Thanks in advance.

Controller:

```
 public ActionResult Abnesager(string searchingAbensager, int? pageNumber)              
    {
      IPagedList<RMAHistory> query = db.RMAStatus.Join(db.RMA_History, u => u.ID, y => y.StatusID, (u, y) => new { u, y })
      .Where(x => x.y.Id.ToString().Contains("00"+searchingAbensager) || x.y.Id.Name.Contains(searchingAbensager) || 
      searchingAbensager == null).Select(t => new RMAHistory
        {

         //Select Something

        }).ToPagedList(pageNumber ?? 1, 10);

            return View(query);
    }
```

View:

```
@model IPagedList<NameSpace.Models.RMAHistory>
@using PagedList;
@using PagedList.Mvc;

    using (Html.BeginForm("Abnesager", "User", FormMethod.Get))
    {

        @Html.TextBox("searchingAbensager", null, new { @placeholder = "ID,Name" })

        <button type="submit">Search</button>

    }

    @Html.PagedListPager(Model, pageNumber => Url.Action("Abensager", new
                            {
                                pageNumber,

                                searching = Request.QueryString["searchingAbensager"]

                            }))

 foreach (var rma in Model)
    {

    <tr>
         <td><span>00</span>@rma.Id</td>
    </tr>

    }
```

Comment: Why would anyone decide to start Ids with 00? I've seen this before and it's the dummest thing ever

Comment: @MarcusHöglund dats wat Employee requested to be like this :)

Comment: @TheFirst You're doing `x.y.Id.ToString().Contains("00"+searchingAbensager)`, which would imply that `x.y.Id` is not already a string.  I see there is a property on it, `Name`, so maybe it is some class which has had `ToString()` overridden?  What does `RMAHistory` look like?

Comment: @TheFirst Not really related to your question, but either make the `searchingAbensager == null` condition the first in your where clause, _or_ remove that condition altogether, and only append the where clause to the query if `searchingAbensager != null`.

Comment: @TheFirst It looks like you're prepending the `RmaHistory.Id` with `00` in the view, which tells me the `Id` property is most likely just an integer, and when you convert it to string there are no leading zeros.  Therefore you should just be doing a `Contains(searchingAbensanger)`, **not** `Contains("00"+...)`.  Perhaps more precisely, you should just be performing an equality comparison.

Comment: @EricLease Id is interger and i convert it to string like this x.y.Id.ToString() and when i do like this Contains(searchingAbensanger) and then search for 00320 its not gonna find any match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply select a substring from the search value, and just search it without adding any 0s

```
public ActionResult Abnesager(string searchingAbensager, int? pageNumber)              
{
    IPagedList<RMAHistory> query = db.RMAStatus.Join(db.RMA_History, u => u.ID, y => y.StatusID, (u, y) => new { u, y })
                                               .Where(x => x.y.Id.ToString().Contains(searchingAbensager.Substring(2)) || x.y.Name.Contains(searchingAbensager) || searchingAbensager == null)
                                               .Select(t => new RMAHistory
                                               {
                                                   //Select Something
                                               }).ToPagedList(pageNumber ?? 1, 10);

    return View(query);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help:)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, `Id` is an integer, and your input can be converted to an integer, and compared for equality.  Then in the view you need only prepend "00" for display purposes.  The view would not change, but the action would.  Correcting for the `x.y.Id.Name` error => `x.y.Name`, and treating `x.y.Id` as an integer, the action becomes...

```
public ActionResultAbensager(string searchingAbensager, int? pageNumber)
{
    var query = db.RMAStatus.Join(
        db.RMA_History, 
        u => u.ID, y => y.StatusID, 
        (u, y) => new { u, y });

    if (searchingAbensager != null)
    {
        int abensager;

        if (int.TryParse(searchingAbensanger, out abensager))
        {
            query = query.Where(x => 
                x.y.Id == abensager || 
                x.y.Name.Contains(searchingAbensager));
        }
        else
        {
            query = query.Where(x =>
                x.y.Name.Contains(searchingAbensanger));
        }
    }

    return View(query
        .Select(t => new RMAHistory { ... })
        .ToPagedList(pageNumber ?? 1, 10);
}
```

Using [predicate builder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx), it might not be so verbose...

```
public ActionResult Abensager(string searchingAbensager, int? pageNumber)
{
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<RMAHistory>();

    if (searchingAbensager != null)
    {
        int abensager;

        if (int.TryParse(searchingAbensanger, out abensager))
        {
            predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Id = abensanger);
        }

        predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Name.Contains(searchingAbensanger));
    }

    return db.RMAStatus.Join(db.RMA_History, u => u.ID, y => y.StatusID, (u, y) => new { u, y })
        //.AsExpandable() // If using Entity Framework
        .Where(predicate);
}
```

perhaps...

```
private static PredicateBuilder.False<RMAHistory> AbensagerPredicate(string searchingAbensager)
{
    var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<RMAHistory>();

    if (searchingAbensager == null) { return predicate; }

    int abensager;

    if (int.TryParse(searchingAbensanger, out abensager))
    {
        predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Id = abensanger);
    }

    predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.Name.Contains(searchingAbensanger));

    return predicate;
}

public ActionResult Abensager(string searchingAbensager, int? pageNumber)
{
    return db.RMAStatus.Join(db.RMA_History, u => u.ID, y => y.StatusID, (u, y) => new { u, y })
        //.AsExpandable() // If using Entity Framework
        .Where(AbensagerPredicate(searchingAbensager));
}
```